# Custom metric or already exist an metric to this problem? Accuracy by ID

Tags: classification, precision-recall

at my company we are working with the "recall" metric in a specific problem, however this metric do not reflect the results that we would like to achieve.
Take a look at below table.
We would like that in case we have any error in an ID, that entire ID/comparison is considered wrong.
So in this case, our metric should return 0%.
Do you suggest that we create a custom metric, or is there any default metric that we could use?

| ID | fruit_1 | fruit_2 | pred_val | real_val | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Banana | Orange | 1 | 0 | FP |
| 1 | Banana | Apple | 1 | 0 | FP |
| 1 | Banana | Banana | 1 | 1 | TP |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | Apple | Banana | 0 | 0 | TN |
| 2 | Apple | Apple | 0 | 1 | FN |
| 2 | Apple | Grape | 0 | 0 | TN |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | Grape | Banana | 1 | 0 | FP |
| 3 | Grape | Apple | 1 | 0 | FP |
| 3 | Grape | Grape | 1 | 1 | TP |

Comment: So in essence your metric should output only 0 and 1, 0 if any are wrong (grouped by ID) and 1 else?

Comment: Yes, you are right,a any suggestion?

Comment: You'll probably need a custom metric, although this doesn't look like a real metric anyway, just a processing step to estimate the actual metric, based on these outcomes.